# Why can't you toggle a function generator's behavior by an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Consider these two functions:

```
def foo():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

def wrap_foo(limit=10, gen=True):
    fg = foo()
    count = 0
    if gen:
        while count < limit:
            yield next(fg)
            count += 1
    else:
        return [next(fg) for _ in range(limit)]=
```

`foo()` is a generator, and `wrap_foo()` just puts a limit on how much data gets generated. I was experimenting with having the wrapper behave as a generator with `gen=True`, or as a regular function that puts all generated data into memory directly with the kwarg `gen=False`.

The regular generator behavior works as I'd expect:

```
In [1352]: [_ for _ in wrap_foo(gen=True)]
Out[1352]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, with `gen=False`, nothing gets generated.

```
In [1351]: [num for num in wrap_foo(gen=False)]
Out[1351]: []
```

It seems like Python pre-classifies the function as a generator based on the presence of the `yield` statement (latter example works perfectly if `yield` is commented out).

Why is this? I would like to understand the mechanisms at play here. I'm running 3.6

Comment: If there is a `yield` in your `def` body, the function will *always be a generator*. A `return` will then act as an implicit `StopIteration`, not as a typical `return` value. Just use `list(wrap_foo(10))` if you want to load the whole thing into memory. Why would you want to do it any other way?

Comment: That's what i figured. I just got lazy at one point in my interactive shell and tried to add a kwarg so I could just get generated data directly instead of always calling `[_ for _ in ...` Then I got curios as to why I couldn't do that.

Comment: But you don't *need* to call `[_ for _ in ...]`, you've abstracted that logic into a generator, so to materialize it just use `list`

Comment: Very true. I was just being dramatic ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems like Python pre-classifies the function as a generator based on the presence of the yield statement

Yes, that's exactly what happens.  `wrap_foo` is determined to be a generator at function definition time.  You could consider using generator expressions instead:

```
def wrap_foo(limit=10, gen=True):
    fg = foo()
    if gen:
        return (next(fg) for _ in range(limit))
    else:
        return [next(fg) for _ in range(limit)]
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like Python pre-classifies the function as a generator based
>   on the presence of the yield statement (latter example works perfectly
>   if yield is commented out).
>
> Why is this?

Because Python can't wait until the function actually executes a `yield` to decide whether it's a generator. First, generators are defined to not execute *any* of their code until the first `next`. Second, a generator might never actually reach any of its `yield` statements, if it happens to not generate any elements.